# Vanilla JS scroll list of items based on mouse position

Tags: javascript, scroll

I'm looking for a pure JS script that can make a list of items scroll vertically but based on the users mouse position above them.

So, if you are hovered on the list but closer to the top, you will see the items near the top of the list and hover over near the bottom you will see the items nearer the end of the list.

I've seen this technique used several times but now I am trying to find an example I can't find one!

It basically allows more content to fit in a small space whilst still allowing access to it all.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you need to start write your own code then if you find any "error", post here and community will help you.

Comment: I was more thinking that it's a common thing to want to do so most likely someone will have already done it and most likely better than I could so, so why re-invent the wheel.

Comment: In my opinion this question is general and in some terms you are asking to copy some code instead of writing it. (we are not a coding service)

Answer (score 0):

You can listen for the `mousemove` event on the element and get the y coordinate of the mouse relative to the element. Then, you can create an interval that scrolls up/down based on whether the relative y coordinate is greater than half the height of the elemet.

You'll also need to add a `mouseleave` event listener that clears the interval so it doesn't keep scrolling after the mouse is no longer hovering over  the element.

```js
const halfHeight = list.offsetHeight / 2;
var interval

list.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  const relativeY = e.clientY - list.getBoundingClientRect().top;
  clearInterval(interval)
  interval = setInterval(() => list.scrollTop += relativeY > halfHeight ? 10 : -10, 100)
})

list.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
  clearInterval(interval)
})
```

```css
#list {
  height: 150px;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="list"><ul><li>1<li>2<li>3<li>4<li>5<li>6<li>7<li>8<li>9<li>10<li>11<li>12<li>13<li>14<li>15<li>16<li>17<li>18<li>19<li>20</ul></div>
```